# SQL Server, TimeSpans

Tags: sql

I am having a trouble in querying my database.. I have a table :

```
**Room**
 +----------------------------------+
 |RoomNo---RoomStatusID---RoomTypeID|
 |  1   ---     1      ---    1     |
 |  2   ---     1      ---    1     |
 +----------------------------------+

**ClientRoom**
 +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
 |ClientRoomNo---RoomNo--------ArrivalDate-------------DepartureDate  |
 |  1         ---  1   ---- 2011-10-03 1:00:00 ---- 2011-10-03 4:00:00|
 |  2         ---  1   ---- 2011-10-03 5:00:00 ---- 2011-10-03 8:00:00|
 +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If I use this query =

```
SELECT Room.RoomNo, RoomType.RoomType
FROM Room INNER JOIN
RoomType ON Room.RoomTypeNo = RoomType.RoomTypeNo
FULL OUTER JOIN ClientRoom ON Room.RoomNo = ClientRoom.RoomNo
WHERE
(((ClientRoom.ArrivalDate <= '10-03-2011 1:00:00' AND
ClientRoom.ArrivalDate <= '10-03-2011 5:00:00') AND
(ClientRoom.DepartureDate <= '10-03-2011 1:00:00' AND
ClientRoom.DepartureDate <= '10-03-2011 5:00:00'))
OR Room.RoomStatusId  = 1)
```

It would return

```
**ClientRoom**
     +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
     |ClientRoomNo---RoomNo--------ArrivalDate-------------DepartureDate  |
     |  2         ---  1   ---- 2011-10-03 5:00:00 ---- 2011-10-03 8:00:00|
     +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Because it reached up to 5:00am in the morning.
But when I change the Arrival and Departure to.. 5:00 - 8:00..
RoomNo 1 is still in the results.
I already tried NOT BETWEEN :(

Comment: What's in the RoomType table?  Why are you using a FULL OUTER JOIN?  That ensures all rows from both tables(the LHS and the RHS of the FOJ) appear in the output, even when there isn't a match.

Comment: RoomType contains the Type of the Room, it does not matter on the query. I use FOJ to merge all available rooms in the Room and CLientRoom

Comment: @TheOxblood - as it stands, you have two redundant where clauses. All operators are `<=`, you can remove the `<=.. 1:00:00` alltogether.

Comment: Im sorry, Im new here in stackoverflow :)

Comment: I want to retrieve all available rooms. I want NOT to retrieve Rooms COVERED by my Arrival and Departure Time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not explain what result you want in what circumstances. But this condition

```
ClientRoom.ArrivalDate <= '10-03-2011 1:00:00' AND 
ClientRoom.ArrivalDate <= '10-03-2011 5:00:00'
```

looks fishy, because the first part is redundant. You could simply say

```
    ClientRoom.ArrivalDate <= '10-03-2011 5:00:00'
```

Same thing for the next part:

```
ClientRoom.DepartureDate <= '10-03-2011 1:00:00' AND
ClientRoom.DepartureDate <= '10-03-2011 5:00:00'
```

This is the same as just saying:

```
ClientRoom.DepartureDate <= '10-03-2011 5:00:00'
```

**Edit**: From the comments I read it, that you have a given timespan *(a,d)* and want to check for each row, if your timespan overlaps with the timespan of the row *(A,D)*. You want to see only non-overlapping rows.

This means your `WHERE` clause must be like this quasicode:

```
WHERE d <= A -- my departure will be before the rows arrival
   OR a >= D -- my arrival is behind the rows departure
```

In full terms:

```
WHERE (    '10-03-2011 5:00:00' <= ClientRoom.ArrivalDate 
        OR '10-03-2011 1:00:00' >=  ClientRoom.DepartureDate 
      )
    OR Room.RoomStatusId = 1
```

**Edit 2**:

What does the query with this fixes? "Show me all schedule rows, which do not conflict with my schedule." But the query should be "Show me the rooms which do not have **any** conflicts with my schedule." That is a completely different beast but easily translated into SQL:

```
SELECT 
    Room.RoomNo
FROM Room
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM ClientRoom
    WHERE 
       Room.RoomNo = ClientRoom.RoomNo
       AND (   '10-03-2011 5:00:00' <= ClientRoom.ArrivalDate 
            OR '10-03-2011 1:00:00' >=  ClientRoom.DepartureDate 
           )
)
OR Room.RoomStatusId  = 1
```

Comment: I also use NOT BETWEEN, but same results. I want to retrieve all available rooms. I want NOT to retrieve Rooms COVERED by my Arrival and Departure Time

Comment: @TheOxblood - you have accepted this answer as being the correct one, yet from your comments, it looks like this does not solve your problem. Wich one is it?

Comment: I want to retrieve all available rooms. I want NOT to retrieve Rooms COVERED by my Arrival and Departure Time

Comment: I am likely this Problem : http://www.tim-carter.com/index.php?t=How+to+check+if+dates+are+overlapping+eachother+with+SQL%3F&Menu=2&SubMenuId=6&ItemId=20

Comment: I have fixed the "full term" section again - it did not match the explanation above. Also: Feel free to upvote also :-)

Comment: In what terms? Syntax Error? Wrong results? Did you use the **exact** version which is visible **now** ?

Comment: I used the EDITED one, not syntax error but wrong results :( can i send you my screenshot for my database relationship?  i need your help badly :(

Comment: WORKING!!! THANKYOUVERYMUCH! If only I could ACCEPT your answer for 1millionth times, I would! Btw, this is for my S.A.D(System And Analysis and Design) subject. It is not SAD anymore, but HAPPY!  :) lol! Thanks!

Comment: Can I ask? What is the use of '1' in the WHERE (SELECT) Clause?

Comment: The job of the subselect is to deliver any conflicting rows. But we actually don't want any data from the rows - it only matters if there is exactly no row or anything else. So `1` tells the DB exactly that: give no data but a mere placeholder (the `1` for each matching row).

Comment: @TheOxblood Please think about this question also on the meta-level: Looking through the conversations - why did it take so long to get the answer? Should I have provided more specific examples or description? And so on. This will help you _very_ much in the next question.

Comment: @A.H. - I have to agree. It took me your final answer to understand the question.